# Is there any drawback if i created a duplicate new Managed Property inside my Search Service which have a user friendly Title

Tags: development, search, display-template, managed-property, crawled-property

I am using a custom display template inside Content Search Web-part inside sharepoint 2013 enterprise. and the display template will be showing the results in a table format. and it will be using the non-friendly managed properties titles as the table columns names, something as follow:-

[image]

where i have 2 managed properties with the following non-friendly names "`PMStatusOWSCHCS`" & "`ExpectedStartDateOWSDATE`" .

so my question is if there is any drawbacks if i go to Central Administration >> Search service >> Search Schema. and from there i created 2 new managed properties which mimic the current ones, but i will define a more user-friendly names such as "PM Status" & "Expected Start Date" .. where these new managed properties will be referencing the same crawled properties as the current managed properties. so could creating these duplicate managed properties cause any of the following problems:-

1. performance issues. slow down the search ??
2. could this results in duplicate search results?

or there is not any harm or significant drawbacks of creating duplicate new managed properties that have user friendly names??

Comment: you dont need to create another managed property, just use an alias or modify the display template

Comment: @GautamSheth i know that i can modify the display template,, but this is really a task i want to avoid ...as i want end users to be selecting the managed properties inside the web part... and also i want to keep the display template clean, since i am using it all over my application.. so i want to have the managed properties having the user friendly names,, and keep the display template as is.. so is my appraoch mentioned inside the original question  valid ?

Comment: @gautam can you advice more on this please ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is valid.

Creating duplicate managed properties :

1) does not affect performance, it does not slow down search

2) it will not result in duplicate search results.

There is no harm or drawback in creating duplicate managed properties.

However, what you are facing is a quite common scenario.

You need not create duplicate managed properties for your requirement. Just adding an alias to existing managed property would suffice.

[image]

So, in your case, in the `PMStatusOWSCHCS` just add the alias as you want and then wait for the crawl to be completed. After that, you can use the alias itself instead of the managed property name.